# C#/.Net : GetResponseAsync taking too much time

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a request that takes approximately 20 seconds at worse and it works perfectly fine when i use a Chrome Extension like Postman or AdvancedREST Client.

My problem is, in C# i used an GetReponseAsync but this seems like it takes forever.
Here is the code :

```
                HttpWebRequest request;
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request.Accept = "application/json";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Proxy = null;

                //The line of code below takes forever and the code never goes further than that
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
```

I don't why does it take so much time, besides, it never crashes or goes through a catch or anything, it just fetches infinitely.

Comment: Is it infinite or is it 20 seconds? If you call this code without an `await` (meaning with a blocking .Result or Wait() ) then you have a deadlock.

Comment: @Crowcoder It is litterally infinite, i waited for 30minutes and nothing happenned so i stopped the code.

Comment: @GPW The ConfigureAwait(false) worked

Comment: [ConfigureAwait(false) is just a hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so you need to use great care.